# MYSQL Add to existing value using two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I would like to add a value to every row in a table. Using a fixed value would give me the following query

```
UPDATE your_table SET displayorder = displayorder + C
```

What would be the right way to run a similar query such that

```
 UPDATE your_table SET displayorder = displayorder + X(C)
```

Whereby C is a constant and X is the value of another column of the same row ? How do I get X which is the value of another column and how do I multiply it by C then add to an existing value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just multiply them together:

```
UPDATE your_table
    SET displayorder = displayorder + X * C;
```

In most programming languages, `*` is used for multiplication.  Parentheses are just used to group expressions.

Comment: Im looking for the multiple of X and C whereby X is another column not the sum.

Comment: @BKCapri . . . I adjusted the answer.